# Hide output in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script, but it gives me annoying output which I don't want to see. Of course I can hide it in that way:

```
./script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

but I want to put the script in "rc.local" or "cron job", so it will be really bad if it received the output every 5 minutes for example, or on boot. It will be great if there is a way to tell the whole script to hide the output.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking - if you never want to see the output, just redirect to `/dev/null` like you're doing.  Perhaps provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? You might be interested in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41381/19157) which discusses suppressing output only if the command succeeds.

Comment: Can't you just put `./script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` in rc.local or crontab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to redirect all output to `/dev/null` *within* the script, that can be done like so (in this case, only performing the redirection if the environment variable `DEBUG` is not set):

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $DEBUG ]] || exec >/dev/null 2>&1
# ...continue with execution here.
```

You could also check for whether your input is from a TTY to detect interactive use:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  # being run by a human, be extra verbose
  PS4=':$LINENO+'
  set -x
else
  # being run by a daemon, be outright silent
  exec >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

See [the bash-hackers page on the `exec` builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec).